# Unable to put some scope data in json in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, firebase

When trying to build a json object from data in $Scope variables, some of the values are not reflected in json.

Below are the details:

**1. In my Controller :**

```
$scope.cart.books = [ ];
$scope.cart.date = "";
$scope.cart.pending = "";

var data = {
   date: $scope.cart.date,
   pending: $scope.cart.pending,
   books: $scope.cart.books
};
```

**I am not getting the value of 'date' and 'pending' when I update it in Firebase, *but values of 'books' array is correctly updated in Firebase***.

But when I log the values of 'date' and 'pending' in console, I am getting the them.
Can someone please suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "I am not getting the value of 'date' and 'pending' "?

Comment: try to define the cart something like this and add the values.`$scope.cart={};
$scope.cart.books = [ ];
$scope.cart.date = "";
$scope.cart.pending = "";`

Comment: I am just getting empty values - " ".

Comment: From the snippet alone, that is all you would get is empty values, show how you are actually filling the variables and how you are saving/retrieving them

Comment: When we need the code how you show/use the `date` and `pending`.

Comment: Do you get empty strings in `date` and `pending` properties? If yes, this seems to be the reference issue. Probably, you are making the `var data` before assigning values to `$scope.cart.pending` and `$scope.cart.date` props. To debug it further, can you add your code chunks on Fiddler?

Comment: Let me try what gihan has suggested. I'll come back once done.

Comment: So I tried as gihan as suggested, but no luck. Still getting empty values( " " ) for $scope.cart.pending and $scope.cart.date props.  @PatrickEvans, I am getting all my props by using 'ng-model' in the view.  If I log them on console (like '$scope.cart.date' ), I am getting values for all props. But If I log them on console (like 'data.date' ), I am NOT getting any values.

Comment: @mak, I am assigning values for all props and then before doing 'submit()', I am making 'var data'.

Comment: @rangma, can you please share the html markup showing scope binding

Comment: @mak,Here it is.     <label class="item item-input">
    <textarea ng-model="cart.pending" placeholder="Pending Books"></textarea>
  </label>

Comment: I am able to get the value into the scope objects. I can log the scope variables in console and see them. But am not able to assign them into 'DATA' json object. Any pointers?

Comment: @rangma, well, this markup seems good. If you are using chrome, you can put a break point just before the definition of `var data` and see what's there in $scope.cart. I suspect, the cart.pending for textarea is not in the same scope where cart.books is.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

I was using a function in another service to get the values.
It was executing as soon as the code was run and assigning default values in *var data*.
So I made a new function and only when it is invoked, the values will be filled in *var data*. 
Thank you everyone for your suggestions specially @Patrick Evans and @mak.